# How can I create a script that move a tfs branch?

Tags: rename, tfvc, tf-cli

I'm trying to create a script that will move a feature branch to an archive area. The script looks like this:

```
mkdir C:\TempWorkspace
pushd C:\TempWorkspace

tf workspace /new /noprompt /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs MoveToArchive
tf workfold /unmap $/ /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

tf workfold /map "$/Fusion Server/Development/%1" C:\TempWorkspace\%1 /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs
tf workfold /map "$/Fusion Server/Development/Archive" C:\TempWorkspace\Archive /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

tf move "$/Fusion Server/Development/%1" "$/Fusion Server/Development/Archive/%1"

tf checkin /comment:"Move %1 to archive"

tf workfold /unmap "$/Fusion Server/Development/%1" /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs
tf workfold /unmap "$/Fusion Server/Development/Archive" /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs
tf workspace /delete /noprompt MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

popd
del C:\TempWorkspace /q /f
```

I get the following error when the move is performed:

`TF14097: Cannot rename $/Fusion Server/Development/B-01560 when it has a working folder mapping assigned to it.`

How can this be done?

**Solution:**

```
mkdir C:\TempWorkspace
pushd C:\TempWorkspace

tf workspace /new /noprompt /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs MoveToArchive
tf workfold /unmap $/ /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

tf workfold /map "$/Fusion Server/Development/" C:\TempWorkspace\ /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

tf get .

tf move "$/Fusion Server/Development/%1" "$/Fusion Server/Development/Archive/%1"

tf checkin /comment:"Move %1 to archive"

tf workfold /unmap "$/Fusion Server/Development" /workspace:MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

tf workspace /delete /noprompt MoveToArchive /s:http://rdsw02fdkserv:8080/tfs

popd
del C:\TempWorkspace /q /f
```

Comment: Are there any user mappings left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't rename a folder that has working folder mappings assigned to it.  Ie, if you have a mapping from $/A to C:\A, you cannot rename $/A.  Instead, unmap $/A and create a mapping for its parent $/, then you can rename $/A to $/B.